# How can I create a custom tag in JPMML?

Tags: logistic-regression, java

I'm trying to create a logistic regression model in jpmml, then write the PMML to a file. The problem I'm having, is that I can't find any way to create a custom tag, such as "shortForm" and "longForm" in the following example:

```
<MapValues outputColumn="longForm">
  <FieldColumnPair field="gender" column="shortForm"/>
  <InlineTable>
    <row><shortForm>m</shortForm><longForm>male</longForm>
    </row>
    <row><shortForm>f</shortForm><longForm>female</longForm>
    </row>
  </InlineTable>
</MapValues>
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
MapValues mv = new MapValues("output")
  .withFieldColumnPairs(
        new FieldColumnPair( new FieldName("gender"), "shortForm" )
  ).withInlineTable(
        new InlineTable().withRows(
                new Row().with???( new ??? )
)))
```

In short, I am asking for an API call I can use to instantiate the "shortForm" element in the example, and attach it to the "row" object. I've been all through the API, examples, and Google/SO, and can't find a thing.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can/should use a generic Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB) approach.

Simply put, call `Row#withContent(Object...)` with instances of `org.w3c.dom.Element` that represent the desired XML content.

For example:

```
Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
Element shortForm = document.createElement("shortForm");
shortForm.setTextContent("m");
Element longForm = document.createElement("longForm");
longForm.setTextContent("male");
row = row.withContent(shortForm, longForm);
```

Comment: @SeanOwen - if it prints the specified output, that will be valid PMML (it's an example from the spec). That's all I'm worried about.

Comment: Ah, row can have any content: http://www.dmg.org/v4-2-1/Taxonomy.html#xsdElement_row  Let me delete/fix comments then.